# Sort models in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say you load up an item starting out on an item page, say `/item/25`.  This will load up Item 1.  Then you transition to the `/items` route, which will load up all the items, but what will happen is that item 25 will be listed first, followed by all item 1 and so on.

How can you sort the models so that they're always displayed the same?

I've tried `this.store.find('item').sortBy('id')`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: why doesn't the sortBy work?  what's the results?  I just missed you are using the sortBy right after the find, and not waiting on it to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

`sortBy` on an empty array would probably return an empty array.  You'll need to wait on the `find` to resolve before using `sortBy`

```
return this.store.find('item').then(function(items){
  return items.sortBy('id');
});
```

Granted, you need to be careful about sorting by `id`, it's a string, and "100" comes before "2".  You may need to define a computed property on your `item` model that coerces it back to an int for sorting purposes.

Comment: Oh. Duh!  I shouldve seen that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an 'ArrayController' for the /items route.
http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/

For your case it would be something like this.

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties:['id']
})
```